# KOMA toc: constant distance between section title and pagenumber

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, page-numbering, tocbasic

For my toc, lof and lot I would like the page numbers to have a constant distance to the chapter, section, etc. titles, wether they have one or two digits. The option `linefill` from the KOMA command `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` only controls the spacing from the right side of the number, same with `pagenumberwidth`.

[image][image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot, listof=totoc, chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[raggedpagenumber=true, linefill={}]{tocline}{part,chapter,section}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[raggedpagenumber=true, linefill={},indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\scshape\roman{page}}
    \addchap{test}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{test}\section{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \chapter{test}
    \setcounter{page}{9}
    \setcounter{chapter}{10}
    \chapter{test}
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \appendix
    \chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand what you are asking for (what you want to align), but you may use the optional argument `pagenumberbox=<command>` to change the alignment of the page numbers in the TOC and other lists.

The option `pagenumberbox=\quad\raggedright` lines up the page number part of the TOC to the left, with a `\quad` distance from the text.

NB! User @esdd has suggested a better solution, use

```
linefill=\quad, pagenumberbox=\mbox
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot, listof=totoc, chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[raggedpagenumber=true, linefill=\quad, pagenumberbox=\mbox]{tocline}{part,chapter,section}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[raggedpagenumber=true, linefill=\quad, pagenumberbox=\mbox,indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\scshape\roman{page}}
    \addchap{test}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{test}\section{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \chapter{test}
    \setcounter{page}{9}
    \setcounter{chapter}{10}
    \chapter{test}
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \appendix
    \chapter{test}
\end{document}
```